# How to .deferReply to specified channel?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

How can I have it so that the bot sends a message to a specific channel, while using `.deferReply` and `.editReply`? Currently, I'm getting an error saying that `suggestionChannel.deferReply is not a function`. Here's my code:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders");
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("suggest")
    .setDescription("Send your suggestion to the specified channel")
    .addStringOption((option) =>
      option
        .setName("suggestion")
        .setDescription("Your suggestion")
        .setRequired(true)
    ),
  async execute(interaction, client) {
    var suggestionChannelID = "900982140504793109";
    var suggestionChannel = client.channels.cache.get(suggestionChannelID);
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setColor("#0099ff")
      .setTitle(`New suggestion by ${interaction.member.displayName}`)
      .setDescription(`${interaction.options.getString("suggestion")}`);
    await suggestionChannel.deferReply();
    await suggestionChannel
      .editReply({
        embeds: [embed],
      })
      .then(function (interaction) {
        interaction.react(``).then(interaction.react(``));
      });
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I have it so that the bot sends a message to a specific
> channel, while using .deferReply and .editReply?

Well, the short answer is; you can't. But you can do this:

As the error already says, `deferReply()` is not a method of the `TextBasedChannels` class, defined by your `suggestionChannel`.

Instead, try *sending* a message to the channel instead of replying. Replies can only be executed in the interaction's channel:

```js
var suggestionChannelID = "900982140504793109";
var suggestionChannel = client.channels.cache.get(suggestionChannelID);
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("#0099ff")
    .setTitle(`New suggestion by ${interaction.member.displayName}`)      
    .setDescription(`${interaction.options.getString("suggestion")}`);

// use this instead
await suggestionChannel.send({
    embeds: [embed],
});
```

P.S side note, `deferReply()` starts a 15-minute timer before the interaction expires and triggers that 'x is thinking...' text to appear when the client is calculating stuff, so try to call it as soon as possible. By default, interactions expire after 3 seconds, so if your bot fails to finish whatever it needs to accomplish within that timeframe, that interaction will fail.